# export graph from html to pdf

Tags: javascript, html

this my graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLemu.png)

this javascript

**function for export to pdf**

```
function generatePDF() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    var elementHTML = document.getElementById("line_top_x").innerHTML;
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    pdf.save('line_top_x.pdf');
}
```

This HTML id is line_*top*_x and has the onclick action of generatepdf(). funtion

```
<div>
    <div id="line_top_x"></div>
    <button onclick="generatePDF()">Export to PDF</button>
</div>
```

> this result
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNgHb.png)

it export just text but don't show graph

i want to export all detail to pdf

Answer (score 0):

this code my graph

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
        data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

        data.addRows([
            [1, 37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
            [2, 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
            [3, 25.4, 57, 25.7],
            [4, 11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
            [5, 11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
            [6, 8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
            [7, 7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
            [8, 12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
            [9, 16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
            [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
            [11, 5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
            [12, 6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
            [13, 4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
            [14, 4.2, 6.2, 3.4]
        ]);

    var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
                subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            axes: {
                x: {
                    0: { side: 'top' }
                }
            }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```